# Dynamic Web Project differences on Eclipse Indigo Release 2

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just downloaded Eclipse Indigo Release 2 and found a difference on my Dynamic Web Project. My WebContent directory (or src/main/webapp with Maven) usually was shown in the project root in the older releases (like a source folder), but not anymore in this new version. Is this a "fix", or something? There is a way to put it in "his place"?

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok, found a file under .settings that have the following:

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
```

However, this doesn't show anything on the Project explorer, I think its just for deploy. The question is still the same: There was any changes on the Release 2? Can I revert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is in `Deployed Resources -> webapp` folder where you can find your sources

Comment: I don't have a Deployed Resources, maybe its some Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: Maybe, I'm using Spring Tool Suite based on Eclipse and don't have clear Eclipse now.

Comment: Just installed JBoss Tools and now my project have this folder (Deployed Resources). hmmm... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that its a fix. Try adding user libraries in the build path of the project. The web project's library will  be added and your WebContent should be shown in the root of the project now.

Comment: The web project's library are in the right place (Java Resources/Libraries/Web App Libraries), WebContent is ok, since its already on the root of the project. Biggest problem is the src/main/webapp =(

Comment: Try switching to a temporary workspace and creating a new project with existing source. See if its solved. Are you facing any problem in deploying the app?

Comment: No problems with deploying, and switching the workspace didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the problem you mentioned, but you can convert your "src/main/webapp" into source folder in eclipse by

Project Java Build path -->> Source Tab -->> Add Folder

Then select your "src/main/webapp folder.

Now your webapp folder will show as source folder in eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, but I wish I had an option to send the WebContent or src/main/webapp to the root of the project, without having to add it as a source folder.